Alignment of nodes to achors given by bases

The base of the anchoring node must align with the horizontal line at 1cm. Also, the base of left and right nodes must align with the base of the anchoring node
The output I want is something like this

My MWE
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\tikzset{help lines/.style=
    {
        line width=0.1pt, opacity=0.25,
    }
}

\tikzset{every node/.style=
    {
        draw, rectangle,
        line width=0.1pt,
        outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,
        draw opacity=0.1,
    }
}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.75, node distance=0pt]
    
    \draw[help lines] (-2,0) grid (2,2);
    
    \draw[line width=0pt] (0,0) -- (0,1)
            node[anchor=base, above=0pt, color=gray, align=left] (anchoring node) {anchoring node}
            node[anchor=north, below=of anchoring node.south] {below}
            node[anchor=base west, right=of anchoring node.base east] {right}
            node[anchor=south, above=of anchoring node.north] {above}
            node[anchor=base east, left=of  anchoring node.base west] {left}
            ;
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Can you show graphically what it should look like at the end?

@cis. I modified the question

You can use base right=of ... etc. to position the nodes with respect to their base:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\tikzset{help lines/.style=
    {
        line width=0.1pt, opacity=0.25,
    }
}

\tikzset{every node/.style=
    {
        draw, rectangle,
        line width=0.1pt,
        outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,
        draw opacity=0.1,
    }
}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.75, node distance=0pt]
    
    \draw[help lines] (-2,0) grid (2,2);
    
    \draw[line width=0pt] (0,0) -- (0,1)
            node[anchor=base, color=gray, align=left] (anchoring node) {anchoring node}
            node[below=of anchoring node] {below}
            node[base right=of anchoring node] {right}
            node[above=of anchoring node] {above}
            node[base left=of anchoring node] {left}
            ;
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thanks for the answer, but the baseline of the anchoring node must also align with the horizontal line at 1cm

@Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Remove the above=0pt to properly align the baseline

May you explain why we need to remove this option? I understand that the baseline should be aligned 0pt above the point (0,1), which should provide exactly the same result as when removed

@Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Sorry, my bad. (however it does nothing useful, so remove it anyway)

The comands above, right etc. also select which anchor to use, which may overwrite the original choice (or select base west instead of base).  BTW, align=left does noting for a single line of text

This is basically a repeat of samcarter's answer, but showing how TikZ handles the positioning internally.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\tikzset{help lines/.style=
    {
        line width=0.1pt, opacity=0.25,
    }
}

\tikzset{every node/.style=
    {
        draw, rectangle,
        line width=0.1pt,
        outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,
        draw opacity=0.1,
    }
}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.75, node distance=0pt]
    
    \draw[help lines] (-2,0) grid (2,2);
    
    \draw[line width=0pt] (0,0) -- (0,1)% starting point for next node
        node[anchor=base, color=gray] (anchoring node) {anchoring node}
      (anchoring node.south) node[anchor=north] {below}
      (anchoring node.base east) node[anchor=base west] {right}
      (anchoring node.north) node[anchor=south] {above}
      (anchoring node.base west) node[anchor=base east] {left}
      ;
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


